# send parameter values to azure notification hub

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to azure. I am sending push notification to Mobile devices through azure notification hub. as example

Send Http POST request --> Azure API --> Azure notification hub --> Android/iOS device

this is my Json (Http POST)

```
{ 
    "text": "Hello Postman local message!",
    "action": "action_a",
    "pageName": "OpenMain", 
    "parameters" : ["WO=1123232", "Test=123"]
    
}
```

I need to send this parameter values to my Mobile devices. Is it possible to send it through notification hub or Do i need to call my API inside my Device to get this Json value. Hope you can understand my question. Please help

Comment: [Notification Hubs templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-templates-cross-platform-push-messages) enable a client application to specify the exact format of the notifications it wants to receive. You can take a look [Azure Notification Hubs for Xamarin](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin)

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT  Thank you very much. I will try it.

Comment: Please feedback if you have solved your problem.